# Ntegrity Siteminder and ASP.NET execution pipeline/page lifecycle

Tags: asp.net, page-lifecycle, siteminder

I'm having trouble integrating SiteMinder and ASP.NET.

The observed behavior for a incoming request is:

1. Global.asax:Application_AuthenticateRequest runs
2. The SiteMinder WebAgent runs

My understanding from my customer's site minder support team is the expected behavior definitely should be:

1. The SiteMinder WebAgent runs
2. Global.asax:Application_AuthenticateRequest runs

The siteminder webagent handler is definitely configured as the first handle in the web.config.

So... my questions are:

1. Can anyone confirm/deny the expected behavior (preferably with a link to documentation)
2. Can anyone point to resources on how to trace web handler execution (ideally I'd like to know for 100% certain which/how/when individual http modules participated in a request)

Also any general advice in dealing with SiteMinder would be appreciated :)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, make sure that SiteMinder ISAPI filter is the first in IIS to process the request.
http://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20SiteMinder%20r12%20SP3-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/idocs/index.htm?toc.htm?834391.html

You also need to make sure that the web.config entries are also in the righ order. 
https://serverfault.com/questions/213379/iis-7-5-siteminder-is-not-protecting-asp-net-mvc-requests/245221#245221